# read(...): Will read remember the change?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

```
On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.
```

This is the description I copy from man 2 read, I have a question to "the file position is advanced by this number" this statement.

What I want to do in my code is the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (read(pipe_fd[i-1][0], &contribution, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("reading from pipe from a child");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (i == argc){
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

I am trying to repeatedly read data from the pipes that connect each child process to my parent process, my question to this post is: will read remember when it should continue reading when next time I call read again?

For example, suppose I am calling `read(pipe_fd[1][0], &contribution, sizeof(int))`, from what I understand here, I know read will read sizeof(int) bytes from the pipe, and somehow use fseek call or something like that to move sizeof(int) bytes to the next new starting position. But when I loop through, and change i back to read(pipe_fd[1][0]) again, will read remember its last starting position? (which is after the first read call, the new starting position I describe above) Or read will just assume nothing happens and read from the initial starting position instead of the new starting position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipes don't have a file position, but `read(2)` will give you all the data written to the other end of the pipe, in the same order (first in, first out).  When you call `read()` the next time on the same fd, you will get the data that follows what you got from the previous call on that fd.  This is typically what you want, and you don't need to do anything special in between.